# date function disregards the default timezone

Tags: php, timezone, php-ini

Following best practice to not modify `php.ini` directly but to have separate files, I have the following file:

```
$ cat /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/99-timezone.ini
[Date]
date.timezone="America/Los_Angeles"
```

I can see that the ini file is being loaded as evidenced by this [phpinfo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zno7g.png).  However in the [date section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWZNP.png) only one of the two directives has updated to show `America/Los_Angeles` and one is `UTC`.  I don't even know where UTC is coming from, as the system's time is not UTC:

```
$ timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2017-11-07 18:36:56 PST
  Universal time: Wed 2017-11-08 02:36:56 UTC
        Timezone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
(snip)
```

I see the following outputs when I run each of these:

```
var_dump(ini_get('date.timezone')); //string(19) "America/Los_Angeles"
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get()); //string(3) "UTC"
var_dump(date('e')); //string(3) "UTC"
```

How do I get the first two to local time?

Comment: If you have a function that "gets" something you usually have a function that will "set" it. Sooo did you go looking for date_default_timezone_get() and find its friend - date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles').

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Thank you Captain Obvious.  If you read the [man page for `date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) then you will notice that it will fall back on the value from php.ini if it wasn't set with `date_default_timezone_set`.  In this case, it's somehow skipping that and returning UTC.

Comment: Might be a silly question but have you restarted Apache since making any changes? Also, are your `var_dump` calls in a `.php` file that you're loading via HTTP, eg `http://localhost/test.php`?

Comment: Yes I have restarted Apache.  I didn't explicitly state it, but the `99-timezone.ini` file is new, and the fact that it shows up in phpinfo indicates that it _is_ being loaded.  Yes, the `var_dump`s are being loaded through Apache, NOT the cli.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I had a feeling you'd checked all that already but it wouldn't be the first time somebody found the configs for the CLI vs HTTP module differed

Comment: Ok, so you don't want to alter php.ini - what happens if you do? Does it change then?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I uncommented `date.timezone` in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`, set it to `America/Los_Angeles`, restarted Apache, and see the same thing with the dumps.

Comment: @sunkerton - are you sure you don't have something else happening in the code. I've got a very similar system here and I can perform all your attempts and get the correct responses... Are you on a local dev setup or on a hosted setup?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw My own bare metal, not "hosting" nor local dev

Comment: Well from everything that has happened it definitely smells like something else is overriding your .ini file settings. Maybe I wasn't being so obvious. I can simulate your exact issue if I have date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); kicking about. But you don't have that do you?  or something in your .htaccess... I see you don't have any other ini files that could cause it. After that I am out of suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWZNP.png), the only way for that to happen (that I know of) is if `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` has been called at runtime. It alters the 'Default Timezone', causing it to differ from the `date.timezone` value in your .ini files.

So look for things like:

- [`auto_prepend_file=`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) in your .ini file. This directive causes a script to be automatically prepended before every PHP file that is processed. If this is in use and the PHP file that it loads sets the timezone, it could cause this.
- Are you using a PHP framework? If so, search the framework's PHP files for `date_default_timezone_set`. As an example, WordPress forces the timezone to UTC.
- If not using a framework, are you using any PHP libraries that may contain `date_default_timezone_set`. If so, that could be the trouble.

---

*The fact that it's showing up like this in your `phpinfo()` output suggests it is an `auto_prepend_file` doing this, because I'm assuming that you're checking phpinfo with a file that only contains `<?php phpinfo();` — no framework or library.*

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with Wordpress.  Luckily I threw the `phpinfo()` inside the code block that was giving me the unexpected date output, had I just done it in a plain file I would've never caught it.